# Image search doesn't work with rotated image

Tags: python, opencv

I have following code:

```
from python_imagesearch.imagesearch import imagesearch


pos = imagesearch("./image_to_find.png")
if pos[0] != -1:
    print(pos[0], pos[1])
else:
    print("image not found")
```

What it does is that it searches your current screen and if it finds the image, it prints its cords.
The problem is it doesn't find the image if it's rotated.

For example when image_to_find.png is this

[image]

and my screen looks like this
[image]

it prints this

> position :  5 144

but if my screen is this
[image]

it prints this

> image not found

Is there any way how to find the image even if it is rotated?

This is what i use:
https://github.com/drov0/python-imagesearch

Comment: Is `imagesearch` rotation invariant? It seems not. This is a limitation of the matching algorithm implemented via correlation. What you can try to do is generate rotated templates and save the highest matching value. Compare this against a threshold to determine if you got a successful match.

Comment: That code is using template matching which is not good for rotation. It literally does a one to one match. For matching with rotation, you would have to use feature descriptor matching. The famous (and patented) ones are SURF and SIFT, both of which are implemented in OpenCV. OpenCV also has it's own called ORB. @eldesgraciado solution is also doable. OpenCV has some functions to rotate images.